# two functions with restrictions and solve for k

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For what value $k$ is the following function continuous at $x=2$?
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2} & x \neq 2 \\
k & x = 2
\end{cases}$$

I was thinking about multiplying the numerator by it's conjugate, but that makes the denominator very messy, so I don't rlly know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *should* multiply by the conjugate, in this case. For $x \neq 2$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt{x+7}}{\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt{x+7}}\\
&= \frac{(2x+5)-(x+7)}{(x-2)(\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt{x+7})}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt{x+7}}
\end{aligned}$$
You can now use this expression to determine the value of $k$.

Comment: thanks, but i don't really know how to use this to get k :(

Comment: Ok. What definition of "continuous" are you using? What do you know about continuous functions?

Comment: yes, like the graph doesn't break

Comment: Does the graph of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt{x+7}}$ "break" at $x=2$? What value do you get when you plug in $x=2$? If $k$ is not equal to this value, then the graph of $f$ would break at $x=2$...

Comment: ohhhh i got it thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Do as you were thinking. Don't expand the denominator and cancel out the factor $x-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the simple solutions already given,you could change variable $x=y+2$ which makes
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2}=\frac{\sqrt{2 y+9}-\sqrt{y+9}}{y}$$ Now, using the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor series, you should find $$\frac{\sqrt{2 y+9}-\sqrt{y+9}}{y}=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{y}{72}+O\left(y^2\right)$$ with $y \to 0$.